# Databinding unresolved after move to Gradle Kotlin DSL build scripts

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I had a working build, including databinding, but after migrating my Gradle build scripts to Kotlin DSL, I now have unresolved symbol errors for every use of `import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil`

My `build.properties.kts` contains the following:

```
plugins {
    id ("com.android.application")
    kotlin ("android")
    kotlin ("android.extensions")
    id ("de.mannodermaus.android-junit5")
}

android {
    lintOptions.isAbortOnError = false

    compileSdkVersion(28)
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles (getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    dataBinding.isEnabled = true

    sourceSets {
        getByName("main").java.srcDir("src/main/kotlin")
        getByName("test").java.srcDir("src/test/kotlin")
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ...
}
```

Is `dataBinding.isEnabled = true` the right way to enable databinding, or do I need to do something else?  (I know I could 'fix' this by going back to Groovy, but that feels a bit too much like giving up!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how i enabled dataBinding in kotlin gradle file :

```
dataBinding {
    isEnabled = true
}
```

Voila ;)

hope this help someone

Comment: This is Groovy. The question *clearly* states I am using Kotlin DSL

Comment: take a look to this [tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/the-new-way-of-writing-build-gradle-with-kotlin-dsl-script-8523710c9670) for more details

Comment: @IainCunningham this is the correct answer, also I used it in this way in `build.gradle.kts`

Comment: Hi, yes, this has changed since 2019.

Comment: @issamux can you edit your answer (somehow) please - I can't change voting until there is an edit (pesky SE timeouts...)

Comment: @iaincunningham yeap i ll edit my post

Answer (score 8):

```
android {
    ...

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
...
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features?hl=en

Comment: This is the correct answer since `databinding.isEnabled = true` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

DEPRECATED:

```
android {
...

buildFeatures {
    dataBinding {
        isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

LATEST APPROACH:

```
android {
...

buildFeatures {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android {
   ...
   dataBinding {
        enable = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: in 2019 `databinding.isEnabled = true` *was* the correct way to enable databinding.

Please now refer to the accepted solution for the right way to do this.

The problem turned out to be in my file naming.  While migrating to Kotlin DSL, I had inadvertently renamed the `gradle.properties` file to `gradle.properties.kts`.  After renaming the file I now have a fully functional build again!

Answer (score 0):

and for ViewBinding you can use :

```
viewBinding.isEnabled = true
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use it like this:

```
android {

  buildFeatures {
         dataBinding = true

         // for view binding:
         // viewBinding = true
    }
}
```